# How to check if a certain date is present in a dictionary and if not, return the closest date available?

Tags: python, loops, datetime

I have a dictionary with many sorted dates. How could I write a loop in Python that checks if a certain date is in the dictionary and if not, it returns the closest date available? I want it to work that if after subtracting one day to the date, it checks again if now it exists in the dictionary and if not, it subtracts again until it finds a existing date.

Thanks in advance

```py
from datetime import timedelta

def function(date):
    if date not in dictio:
        date -= timedelta(days=1)
    return date
```

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python datetime closest date", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.  You can do better than your trial-and-error loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a recursive function to solve your problem:

```py
import datetime
def find_date(date, date_dict):
    if date not in date_dict.keys():
        return find_date(date-datetime.timedelta(days=1), date_dict)
    else:
        return date
```

I don't know what is the content of your dictionary but the following example should show you how this works:

```py
import numpy as np

# creates a casual dates dictionary
months = np.random.randint(3,5,20)
days = np.random.randint(1,30,20)
dates = {
    datetime.date(2019,m,d): '{}_{:02}_{:02}'.format(2019,m,d) 
    for m,d in zip(months,days)}

# select the date to find
target_date = datetime.date(2019, np.random.randint(3,5), np.random.randint(1,30))

# print the result
print("The date I wanted: {}".format(target_date))
print("The date I got: {}".format(find_date(target_date, dates)))
```

Comment: yes a recursive function could work really well. Thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is possibly a while loop, although beware because if it will not find the date it will run to infinite. Perhaps you want to define a limit of attempts until the script should give up?

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

d1 = {
    date(2019, 4, 1): None
}

def function(date, dictio):
    while date not in dictio:
        date -= timedelta(days=1)

    return date


res_date = function(date.today(), d1)
print(res_date)
```

Comment: Yes that would make sense. Thank you